# How two create a two-column dynamic layout from varied-width content with CSS?

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I am trying to create a CSS for a product information page, and am having some issues with setting the width dynamically based on the content.

We want to display a product image next to a product description.  The image HEIGHTS are all consistent; the image WIDTHS vary. We want the text column width to size dynamically based on what's left over after the images are placed.

Where it gets trickier is that we want the flexibility to use an image in EITHER the right or left column.

```
<div id="leftcolumn"><img src="yellowscraper"></div>
<did id="rightcolumn"><p>[yellowscraper text]</p></div>

<div id="leftcolumn"><p>[brown scraper text]</p></div>
<div id="rightcolumn"><img src="brownscraper"></div>

<div id="leftcolumn"><img src="marmite"></div>
<did id="rightcolumn"><p>[marmite text]</p></div>

<div id="leftcolumn"><p>[yellowscraper text]</p></div>
<div id="rightcolumn"><img src="yellowscraper"></div>
```

[image: Mockup]

Consider:

```
#leftcolumn {float: left}
#rightcolumn {float: right}
.clear { clear: both;}
```

But I have no idea how to define the `width` parameter. The column that contains an image would be the width of the image. The OTHER column would be what remains...basically the container width minus the image width.

Is there some cool CSS trick to accomplish this? I suspect I may just be aligning text to the right or left of images, but I'd love to know if there's a CSS way to make this happen.

Comment: Is that image what you're trying to achieve or what you've got so far?

Answer (score 0):

Using floats should work fine - it's not quite a columnar layout, stuff just... hangs where it wants to hang.

http://jsfiddle.net/FD5Uy/

Is that what you're asking for? Notice I only put the float on the div containing the image, instead of left on the image and right on the text:

```
<div class="float-left"><img></div>
<p>
    The image will be to the left of this paragraph,
    I don't need to float this tag to the right...
</p>
<div class="float-right"><img></div>
<p>
    Same same...
</p>
```

You can apply the float class directly to your images if you don't need the div for anything else, it'll still work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, the best way to do this is tables. Just make the borders invisible when you do it, and float the images inside the table, with the following CSS:

```
#left {
float:left;
}
#right {
float:right;
}
```

Next up, set up your table like this.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><div id="left"><img src="yellowscraper"></div></td>
<td><div id="right"><p>[yellowscraper text]</p></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div id="left"><p>[brownscraper text]</p></div></td>
<td><div id="right"><img src="brownscraper"></div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment if you have any questions.